# How to change the color of the android actionbar without using any image resource?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I want to change the color of my actionbar but I'm no good at making image resources so I want to know if there is anyway it is possible to do that without images. like setting a color to some property or something? I surfed a lot but there are too many confusing answers and I can't figure out which one to use.
I am developing for sdk above 8 so I'm using support libraries. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have easily found out the answer [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html). Or you can [click here](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/) to create image resources very easily. But anyway, this is how you do it.
first of all, define a color you want for your actionbar in "colors.xml" in the "values" folder of your project like this:

```
    <color name="customColor">#f1f1f1</color>
```

Then create a new .xml file in your drawable folder with the name say "actionbar_drawable.xml". It has to be a "shape" drawable.

drawable\actionbar_drawable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >    
    <solid 
        android:color="@color/customColor"/>    
</shape>
```

Now create "themes.xml" in "values" folder with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <style name="CustomActionBar" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
       <item name="android:actionBarStyle" tools:targetApi="11">@style/CustomBar</item>
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
       <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/CustomBar</item>         
    </style>

    <style name="CustomBar"
         parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
       <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_drawable</item>
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
       <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_drawable</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Then in your manifest file, set the theme for your activity like this:

```
android:theme="@style/CustomActionBar"
```

That's all. Now you won't have to make any image resource. Hope it's helpful to you.

Answer (score 3):

Generate what ever theme you want from [Android Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/)

Copy all the files it generates to the respective folders in res folder and VOILA.. ;)

Comment: Now it seems easier. :) Thank you so much. But still isn't there anyway to do it without images? Lemme check the other answer if it works.

Comment: Even the other ans is correct. But for that you need to set the color to the action bar in every activity. Where as if you follow my solution you need not do anything. Action bar theme will be set and same action bar will be used throughout your application.

Answer (score 1):

```
activity.getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.my_color)));
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I forgot to mention that I wanted to do this through xml. My apologies. But I'm sure your answer would definitely help me in future.